# Memory leak when using ribbon commands (office-js)

Tags: memory-leaks, command, office-js

I'm developing an Excel add-in that makes extensive usage of commands in the ribbon. I noticed that every time I executed a command, the memory usage of the Internet Explorer process corresponding to the add-in increased, but it does not decreased after the processing is finished.

At first I thought it was a problem with my code, so I created new Add-in with a single command and a very simple function (write some values to a worksheet), and the same behavior occurred. I have noticed that the memory increase happens before even reaching my code in the Functions file.

It is possible to reproduce the issue in Word as well, using the "Simple Add-in Commands Sample" from the OfficeDev Github site.

Steps:

1. Go to https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/Simple. Side load or deploy the Add-in fillowing the instructions in the section "Deploying the Sample".
2. When the Add-in is running, open the task manager and locate the Internet Explorer process corresponding to the add-in.
3. Click the "Execute function" button in the "Test Tab" tab. Some text is written to the doc. Notice that the memory usage of the IE process increases every time the function is executed. Keep clicking the button, ultimately, the add-in crashes.
4. Interestingly, if you click the "Show Taskpane" button, and then close the taskpane using the X button, the memory usage of the IE process drops to the initial values.

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround to release the memory manually, at least for now?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of excel?  [or office, for that matter]

Comment: Anyway, I won't have a definitive answer, but googling "memory leak ribbon" there are MANY results, for various reasons. You may have to let the project owner know what you have discovered.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, we are investigating this issue.